Evaluating Hypergeometric function for $z \geq 1$ for a degenerate case
I am trying to evaluate the following Hypergeometric function $_2F_1[1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},z]$, where, $z \geq 1.$ Since, I have $c \, (3/2)-b \, (1/2) = 1$, this is referred as a degenerate case in Bateman et al. vol 1. In addition, I have $c-a-b=0$. I can find nice expressions for the asymptotic case, i.e., when $z \gg 1$; however, I also need to evaluate this function for $z \geq 1$.
In Mathematica, $z \geq 1$ gives me complex values. But that wouldn't be a correct for the problem I am trying to solve. Is there any alternate way to evaluate this?

Outside my area of expertise. Unless I specified it incorrectly, Wolfram Alpha tells me that for $z \ge 1$, $_2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};z\right) = \frac{\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}$.

For $z \gt 1$, $\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)$ must necessarily be complex. Based on that, I would suggest adding information about the problem you are trying to solve.

@njuffa. The real and imaginary parts are very nice.

https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E3

$$f(a,z)=\,_2F_1\left(a-\frac{1}{2},a;a+\frac{1}{2};z\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\,z^n$$ where
$$\alpha_n=\frac{(2 a-1)\, \Gamma (n+a)}{(2 n+2 a-1)\,
   \Gamma (a)\, \Gamma (n+1)}$$
$$a=1\qquad \implies \qquad\alpha_n=\frac{1}{2 n+1}$$
$$f(1,t^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {t^{2n}}{2n+1}=\frac 1 t\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\frac 1 t\tanh ^{-1}(t)$$
$$f(1,z)=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}$$ as already given by @njuffa in comments.
If $z>1$ the result is complex. But
$$\Re\left(\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {(2 n-1) z^n}=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}$$
$$\Im\left(\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{z}}\right)=-\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{z}}$$
